# Custom WebApp not appearing in Unity Launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, webapps

I created a custom webapp in order to have it in the Unity launcher. The thing is that I followed some instructions found on the web and I can actually search for it in the dash. I click on it and it opens Firefox and it goes to the proper destination. So, that's good.

Now, what I want is for the webapp to appear in the launcher when it is launched from the dash so that I can right-click on it and select "Lock to launcher", but that does not happen.

I know this question has been asked already (https://askubuntu.com/questions/232291/custom-unity-web-app-not-appearing-in-the-launcher) but it did not get a single reply.

Does anybody know how to make the webapp visible in the launcher?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I found the way.

I just had to drag and drop the icon from the Dash to the Unity Launcher. Now it is locked there.